# Doesn't recognize USB

Tags: boot, drivers, 16.04, usb

I plug my USB 3.0 into my USB 3.0 port on the left side of my laptop and nothing happens. Now some backstory. I manually updated the Linux kernel to 4.8.1 that came out recently and my computer wouldn't start up so I booted into the previous ones and decided to plug in my USB which worked at the time! But then I move some files to the USB and delete some old files which all worked at the time but then I unplug it and try to plug it in again and voila it just doesn't load, other USB's work however. I've tried sooo much. I've tried plugging it into a live disk machine using a different USB and still didn't work. I've tried numerous things from different sites to no avail. I've tried using the USB on two different Windows machines one is 7 and the other is 8 still nothing. My one and only KeepassX file is on this USB along with 400 pictures (memories) that I really don't feel like losing so I NEED to get this USB working again. Please. If there is any other information needed I will provide it. I just need this working again. Doesn't show up in 'fdisk -l' but shows up in lsusb as 'Kingston Technology DataTraveler G4'.

**lsusb:**

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 064e:c33c Suyin Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 138a:0018 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint scanner
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler G4
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 1d57:0005 Xenta Wireless Receiver (Keyboard and Mouse)
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**dmesg:**

```
[ 2037.113744] usb-storage 6-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2037.113927] scsi host9: usb-storage 6-2:1.0
[ 2038.180694] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2038.181522] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 2069.129200] usb 6-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 2074.144279] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[ 2074.248216] usb 6-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 2079.264401] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[ 2079.892299] usb 6-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 2079.900324] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 2079.900332] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 2079.900369] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2079.900378] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 2079.900406] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 2079.900412] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2079.900744] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

**lsblk:**

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                  8:2    0   488M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                  8:3    0 930.5G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt        252:0    0 930.5G  0 crypt 
    ├─mint--vg-root   252:1    0 923.1G  0 lvm   /
    └─mint--vg-swap_1 252:2    0   7.5G  0 lvm   
      └─cryptswap1    252:3    0   7.5G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: If u don't see it in Disk management in windows... usb is dead

Comment: @minigeek I haven't tried Disk Management but it will be under the devices but it'll give me _'USB Device is Not Recognized. The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it.'_

Comment: ...got ur problem..ur pendrive is safe..just partition is unformatted...i.e neither ntfs nor fat or ext4..u will need AOMEI, or PARTITION WIZARD MINI TOOL to detect the pendrive and then u can right click it delete partition and create new as primary partition with ntfs format! Thats it...u can't do it through windows disk management..u can also do it via gparted installed in ubuntu..just follow some guides

Comment: Does your disk get assigned a ID like dev/sdb?

Comment: @minigeek I've tried using gparted and the USB doesn't come up. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MarkKirby No, it doesn't...

Comment: Laptop or Desktop?

Comment: I'm using a laptop. @MarkKirby

Comment: Long shot, it could be a power supply issue, usb 3 needs a lot of power, see here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114901/127869 it was this guys issue, can you try a desktop? Same error `failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT`

Comment: @MarkKirby I don't have a desktop and this just happened after I updated the kernel, I've tried it on 3 different computers though to no avail and I can't reinstall the OS as all of my passwords are on this USB.

Comment: Install this `sudo apt-get install testdisk` and run it `testdisk` now press enter on `create log` is your disk shown in this screen?

Comment: @MarkKirby It's not shown and I tried plugging it into all the ports I have and re-running it. The USB also doesn't mount, if that helps. Thanks for the response and suggestions.

Comment: Use mini tool partition wizard on windows and let us know.... gparted by default shows internal hard-disk...did u select usb from drop down menu on right corner..if this doesn't help.. then may b mini tool can help u..i use it a lot..but that will make u erase everything in pendrive(there is also option to recover data from raw memory-u can try that too to recover data)

Comment: Meanwhile post output of lsblk after connecting usb

Comment: @minigeek I click on the drop down menu and it's just my hard-disk that shows. I don't really want to erase everything on it, I'm more worried about the content on the USB than the USB itself but I'll try the recover data later as it's 4am right now. I'll edit the main post with the lsblk output.

Comment: Yesterday my friends 1TB hardisk got dead ..i followed all possible solutions..on windows on Linux...But didn't help...if os can't recognise it even after manually mounting..it has to be declare dead

Comment: Nope..lsblk.not showing in sdb output....next time whenever u eject usb from windows choose safely remove and in ubuntu safely eject or simply unmount button in ubuntu...i made my one usb dead not doing that... gud luck :(

Comment: @minigeek So the new kernel update killed my USB?... I haven't lost hope yet, there's gotta be a way...

Comment: Ya let me know... after u do..i also have one hard-disk like urs

Answer (score 0):

Based on the many attempts you tried with various systems I would strongly assume that the USB stick is dead or damaged.

You can carefully try some rescue software and see if the data can be retrieved.

Comment: There's gotta be something I can do. If the USB is detected then there's gotta be something, right?... What kind of software would you recommend? Would it be possible to take it into a shop and see if they could recover it?

Comment: Yes. There is something being detected so chances are good that something can be retrieved. There are many free tools available but it has been some time since I did that the last time so unfortunately I can' t give a recommendation. There are well known companies, too but this would probably be quite expensive.

Comment: Dang... I was looking at TestDisk but I wouldn't really know where to start with that and I've tried Recuva on one of the Windows machines. Ballpark me a price if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I would, first of all, try recovering the data from the drive and then proceed to follow others' instructions on how to possibly get it back. Unless the data on it doesn't matter for you.

I'm wondering if it shows up in gParted because, as far as I know, gParted also looks at unmounted devices?

Comment: Thanks for the response! The data means a lot. It's got my one and only KeepassX file on it (which is ALL of my passwords) and 400 pictures that mean a lot to me. I never thought twice of having another backup method because this is a relatively new USB and didn't think it'd die. It doesn't show in gParted and know any good way to recover the data if there's not other way?

Comment: Beware of the bathtub curve.  New and old devices have the highest failure rate..